# Get latest record in Django from two tables by comparing the date

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have two models - New User Request and Existing User Request which contain exactly the same fields

```
class new_user_request(models.Model):
    request_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    request_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)


class existing_user_request(models.Model):
    request_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    request_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

**How Table Entries are made?**

> When the employee raises a request from frontend, a check is perform
> to see if there exists an entry in the **new_user_request** table for
> that employee.
>
> If it does exist, entry is made to **existing_user_request**, if not
> the entry is made to **new_user_request**

My task is to send notification mails to employees starting from 3 days before their access expires.

I need help in getting the records of employees based on the following conditions:

> - If record exists in **existing_user_request** get the records whose expiry is in the next three days.
> - If record does not exist in **existing_user_request**, get the records from **new_user_request** where the expiry date is in the next
>   three days.

If there is a django way of doing this please let me know, if not please help me with the sql query so that I could run this as a cron job.

Comment: It looks strange to have two tables in the first place, this will make querying a lot harder.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand, but changing the database structure is not in my hands.

Comment: Is there any problem with querying both tables and combining the results to only have distinct items (maybe using a `set`)? The actions you are taking are exactly the same too.

Comment: @shriakhilc I can do that for sure. But how would I check for the expiry? Also, was just checking if there is a better way?